# Convert many saved webpages to PDF

Tags: windows-7, pdf, html, document-converter

I have many saved webpages (.html, .htm), I would like to convert all of them to PDF files (1 webpage to 1 PDF, no merging) at once.

What tool would you recommend? I would like to create PDF files with text, not bitmap, so I could search in PDF file and copy text from it. I also want the PDF to have the same filename as the HTML file (just different extension of course).

Comment: For which operating system(s)?

Comment: Good point, Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Though with a different background, I'm using **[PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/)** for that. Conversion is as simple as calling `prince file.html`, which results in `file.pdf` as you specified in your question. Fine-Tuning is of course possible: via CSS, and using command-line options.

*PrinceXML* is free for personal, non-commercial use.

Comment: This is strange. It seems that I am able to export website from url fine, but not from saved web pages in html. I get many errors eg. error parsing attribute name.

Comment: I use it for complex local pages (my books), and cannot remember such an error. Are those saved pages syntactically OK? When in trouble: Price support is pretty good, just check their forums.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into [wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for converting a web page to PDF. It is free and open source, runs on Windows, OS X, and Linux. Between shell and command line options, it will do most anything with files and naming that you need. The PDF files are textual, but you will certainly need a search engine that understands PDF formats to properly search them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDF creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) to convert pages from any application to PDF files.
After installing PDF Creator you have to use the print command and then select PDF Creator from the printer list.
This will convert the pages from any application to PDF which support page printing.

For your *saved* webpages: just reopen them in your browser, then print.